# How to disable login into AIX using password for any means

Tags: ssh, password, login, aix

Is there any way to disable login to AIX using password?
I know that for SSH login I can update sshd_config and set PasswordAuthentication to no.
But what about other ways of login into AIX, like telnet, ... ?
I have to forbid login with password for any means.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the services that need these password logins. Telnet is insecure anyways.

See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/tutorials/aix/section3.html for securing and disabling unnecessary services.